# Vanilla JS - ES6: .map() is not a function

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6

I am trying to refactor my *for loop* with .map() and ES6 and I am getting an error message stating  ".map is not a function"

```js
//basic tab function
function openContent(tabpages) {
  var page = document.getElementsByClassName("content");

  // for (i = 0; i < page.length; i++) {
  //   page[i].style.display = "none";
  // }
  page.map(page => (page.style.display = "none"));

  document.getElementById(tabpages).style.display = "flex";
}
```

Please point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`page` is an HTMLCollection which is an Object not an Array. You can extract the object's keys to an array for mapping using `Object.keys()`

For example:

```js
//basic tab function
function openContent(tabpages) {
  var page = document.getElementsByClassName("content");

  // for (i = 0; i < page.length; i++) {
  //   page[i].style.display = "none";
  // }
  Object.keys(page).map(idx => (page[idx].style.display = "none"));

  document.getElementById(tabpages).style.display = "flex";
}
```

Comment: that worked but it has gotten more verbose. should I stick to the simple for loop?

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned, `getElementsByClassName` doesn't return an array, so you cannot call `.map` on it.

The simplest way to convert to an array would be to use `Array.from`:

```
var page = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("content"));
```

However, `.map` is not the right tool for what you are doing. `.map` creates a new array from the return values of the callback. But you don't actually intend to use that array.

You simply want to iterate over all elements. You can do this easily without converting the node list to an array, using `for...of`:

```
for (var page of document.getElementsByClassName("content")) {
  page.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: What I wanted to say, map() creates new array so that wasnt the right way.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I really appreciate this. A newbie like can really learn a lot from you. I was just experimenting with ES6 and higher order functions since it is suppose to make our lives easier as developers and ended learning new things. You guys are awesome!

Comment: `Array.from` - nice. This should be the accepted answer. Excellent approach

Answer (score 2):

Given that you're iterating over the elements, and not — from the code you've posted — doing anything with the Array returned from `Array.prototype.map()` Id suggest using `document.querySelectorAll()` and `NodeList.prototype.forEach()` to iterate over that NodeList:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.content').forEach( (page) => page.style.display = 'none' );
```

Although I'd also recommend using a class to hide the elements, rather than modifying the inline-styles directly:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.content').forEach( (page) => page.classList.add('hidden') );
```

Obviously that does require a CSS definition for the `hidden` class-name.

References:

- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
- [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).

Comment: Just read the documentation and refactored the code using it. Thanks man!

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of some help!